# How to fix no color after adding new rule in conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I added `=IF(O2&P2="","",IF((O2="Yes")*(P2="Yes"),"Yes",""))` in the new rule of the conditional formatting and already set a color if the condition is met, but in the end no color appears.

May I know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you would like to color a cell if both O2 and P2 have the value "Yes" in them.

If this interpretation is correct, then this is how to do it. In my example, I will color the background of the cells in column P if the condition is met but the same approach can be used whichever column you want to format. I also have added some additional data for the demonstration:

[image]

- Select the cells you want to shade (P2 to P9 in my example)
- Select 'Conditional Formatting' > 'New Rule'
- Select 'Use formula to determine which cells to format'
- Enter this formula

  =AND(O2="Yes",P2="Yes")

*or you can use a more complex formula if you want - but this is the same as your formula in that it yields true if both are "Yes" false otherwise*

- Select format and choose the color, or other format criteria

[image]

- and that should do it...#

[image]

I hope I interpreted your question correctly and that this helps.